# MS-ACCESS find data older than 3 years

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to have a push button that finds all records that are older than 3 years. I have a push button (named `Expiring`) on a combo box that searches a field `Intro Date` in table `RECS`. Here is what I have:

```
Private Sub Expiring_Click()
Call Search
End Sub

Sub Search()
Dim task As String

Me.Refresh

task = "SELECT * FROM RECS WHERE DateDiff('m', Date(), [Intro Date])" > 36
DoCmd.ApplyFilter task

End Sub
```

This does not work, I get a type mismatch for my `task` line. I simply want a push button that will only show data that is 3 years old. . .

I am super new to MS-ACCESS and SQL/VBA. This code was based off another function I created that searches if `Intro Date` older than a date specified in a unbounded box.

Comment: Just move the double quotes to after 36 to enclose the full string: 
task = "SELECT * FROM RECS WHERE DateDiff('m', Date(), [Intro Date]) > 36"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correct line of code

```
task = "SELECT * FROM RECS WHERE DateDiff('m', Date(), [Intro Date]) > 36"
```

You were comparing text to the number 36 the result is a boolean instead of a string

Comment: Well don't I feel silly. Thanks, that works! Although I did have to switch ```Date()``` and ```[Intro Date]``` within the ```DateDiff``` function.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by others, the issue with your code is that the comparison operator lies outside of the SQL statement -

```vb
task = "SELECT * FROM RECS WHERE DateDiff('m', Date(), [Intro Date])" > 36
```

Should be:

```vb
task = "SELECT * FROM RECS WHERE DateDiff('m', Date(), [Intro Date]) > 36"
```

---

### DateDiff Considerations

When calculating temporal differences using the [`DateDiff`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/datediff-function-e6dd7ee6-3d01-4531-905c-e24fc238f85f) function, consider that the choice of interval argument will impact the accuracy of the result.

For example, the intuitive solution might be to calculate the three-year range by supplying the `DateDiff` function with the `yyyy` interval and the two dates in question, and simply check whether the result is greater than 3:

```vb
DateDiff("yyyy", Date(), [Intro Date]) > 3
```

However, observe that this will omit all dates whose year components differ by `3` or less, not dates which are exactly 3 years or fewer apart - **meaning that up to an extra year's worth of time may be excluded from your results**:

```vb
?datediff("yyyy", #2018-01-01#, #2021-01-01#) ' 3 years apart
 3
```

```vb
?datediff("yyyy", #2018-01-01#, #2021-12-31#) ' 3 years + 364 days apart
 3
```

Similarly, if you opt for the month interval (`m`), the remainder of a month three years in future will also be excluded:

```vb
?datediff("m", #2018-01-01#, #2021-01-01#) ' 3 years apart
 36
```

```vb
?datediff("m", #2018-01-01#, #2021-01-31#) ' 3 years + 30 days apart
 36
```

Obviously we now descend into an infinite regression: *if days are selected, the time component will be ignored, if hours are selected, the minutes component will be ignored, ad infinitum...*

And so ultimately, the choice of interval depends upon the requirements of the application: if your application requires that something expire or be validated exactly 3 years *to the day*, then if using the `DateDiff` function, the day interval (`d`) should be used (and note that this would include leap days, and so the resulting date could be a day prior to the date 3 years earlier); if the remainder of the month is permitted, then the month interval (`m`) may suffice.